# Use of .BY and .EACHI in the data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get a better grasp on how some of the special variables in the `data.table` package work.  One of these is the `.BY` statement.  I have not seen a lot of examples of people using it, but the documentation implies that is is useful in plotting.

For example, the following code seems to work quite well (showing a plot for each of the species and assigning the right title to each plot) in `data.table 1.9.3`:

```
iris <- data.table(iris)
iris[,plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, main = unlist(.BY)), by = Species]
```

While this code does not work as intended by me:

```
iris[ , plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, main = .BY), by = Species]
```

Why are these two different?  From the comments, it does not seem to be an issue in `data.table 1.9.2`. In what other ways might it be useful to use the `.BY` statement?  How is this different compared to the `.EACHI` statement?

Comment: I get identical results using both of your statements. What is supposed to be different?

Comment: Interesting...I just tried this with ```data.table``` 1.9.2 and I got identical results (but with the titles being 1,2, and 3).  But in 1.9.3, I get different results for the two pieces of code (one with the Species names and one returns an error).

Comment: Yep, I'm using 1.9.2 - it's probably worth editing your post to include that this is an issue present in 1.9.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.BY` is a *named* `list` containing the values of the `by` variables.

Passing an unnamed list to `main` will work, however a *named* list will fail (wholly unrelated to `data.table`

```
plot(1, main = list(1))
# works....
plot(1, main = list(s=1))
# Error in title(...) : invalid graphics parameter
```

There is a recent commit to data.table 1.9.3 which fixed a bug to do with naming in `.BY
[Closes bug #5415. .BY gets names attribute set properly](https://github.com/Rdatatable/datatable/commit/673c8d848924ed95185f803c2e4b0eb009dca69d) in april this year.

If you had more than 1 "by" variable, you would want to be able to concatenate some how

perhaps

```
iris[,plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,main=do.call(paste,.BY)),by=Species]
```

will work (unless you have a column called `collapse`!)

`EACHI` is completely unrelated to this. Please read the [NEWS for data.table 1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v194--on-cran-2-oct-2014) for an understanding of this.