# How is the R data.table `.BY` operator used?

Tags: r, data.table

the data.table vignette defines the special symbol `.BY` as

> .BY is a list containing a length 1 vector for each item in by. This can be
>   useful when by is not known in advance. The by variables are also available to j
>   directly by name; useful for example for titles of graphs if j is a plot command,
>   or to branch with if() depending on the value of a group variable.

This description is confusing to me.  How and when would I use `.BY`?  Even for titles of graphs?  Why was it added as a special symbol?

`example("data.table")` doesn't have any examples, and I haven't found any on the data.table wiki page.  I don't know how to search on stack overflow for data.table and .BY usages either.  I keep getting hits that use the `by` operator in `data.table`

Comment: Here's a slightly trickier use of `.BY` from an old answer of mine too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129750/data-table-drop-key-rows-and-summarize/25130426

Comment: ...and yes, it is tough to search for. Maybe dot-BY or something could be used to make it easier.

Comment: Related: [r - Use of .BY and .EACHI in the data.table package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153174/use-of-by-and-eachi-in-the-data-table-package). Regarding your "_I don't know how to search on stack overflow for data.table and .BY_", it's generally more efficient to use google instead of searching from within SO (see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286485/stack-overflow-search-returns-no-results-but-google-search-returns-2-000) and links therein). The link above was the second hit on my google search '`R data.table ".BY"`'.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1363

Comment: Also be aware that documentation about that has been recently improved, up-to-date manual can be found in [?"special-symbols"](http://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/special-symbols.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing how `.BY` can be passed through to further arguments like a plot title. Using the built-in `mtcars` data:

```
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
layout(1:3)
mtcars[, plot(mpg, main=paste("Cylinders:", as.character(.BY))), by=cyl]
```

[image]

Comment: In this particular case it's simple to just replace `.BY` with `cyl`. `.BY` is actually more useful when we do not know in advanced what the grouping column will be, so we can refer to it from `j` expression. Your example could be ideally wrapped in a function that takes arbitrary column to group by.